# How to trigger an onClick() event

Tags: jquery, onclick, radio-button

I have this markup:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Y" name="addNextGroup[1][]">
<input type="checkbox" value="Y" name="addNextGroup[2][]">
<input type="checkbox" value="Y" name="addNextGroup[3][]">
<input type="checkbox" value="Y" name="addNextGroup[4][]">
<input type="checkbox" value="Y" name="addNextGroup[5][]">
```

I need to create an onclick event listener so I can launch a function in jquery.
I am trying to piece it together like this, but I feel it is wrong:

```
for(i=1; i<=5; i++) {
  var myEl + i = document.getElementsByTagName('addNextGroup\\[' + i + '\\]\\[\\]');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply:

```
$('input[name^="addNextGroup"]').click(function(){...})
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you so much @j08691

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can think to do this is to add to the mark up:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Y" name="addNextGroup[1][]" onclick='function();'>
```

If you must use jquery, first add a class to all the input elements that you would like to trigger the function onclick with like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Y" name="addNextGroup[1][]" class='listener'>
```

Then add jquery code like this to the JS file.

```
$(".listener").click(function(){
    ENTER FUNCTION HERE
});
```

EDIT:

You may have to have that Jquery line above inside the following jquery (maybe not I am rusty):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```